# Android ServerSocketChannel binding to loopback address

Tags: java, android, timeout, connect, nio

I have an Android device that will be running a server that other Android devices, the clients, will be connecting to. I am using `SocketChannel` and `ServerSocketChannel` in non-blocking mode.

Here is my code for initializing the ServerSocketChannel on the server device:
            ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;
            ServerSocket serverSocket;

```
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), 10000);

        serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        serverSocket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
        serverSocket.bind(address);

        serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        Log.i("AdminNetwork", serverSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
```

When client devices attempt to connect to the server device the connections time out and a ConnectException with a null message is thrown. I put the call to `Log.i()` to check the IP address the ServerSocket is binding to. When the code executes the output says the IP address is '127.0.0.1'. I tried the code in a normal Java application and it printed the internal IP address of the computer. When I have the server running on a computer the clients connect successfully.

I think the problem is that the ServerSocket is binding to the loopback address, causing client connections to fail. Is this the problem that causes the clients to time out? If it is how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a possibility. `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` could return `127.0.0.1` or `::1` or any of the other IP addresses local to the server.

Just pass `null` instead of this value: this is equivalent to `INADDR_ANY`, which allows the server to accept connections via any of its interfaces.

Comment: Tested it and the client connected. Thanks!